# Data is not updating in mysql through laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have made a table of users and during the time of registration, i am inserting the necessary data like email password and name and marked others columns null. Everything was working fine until i tried to update the null columns as per requirement. I have tried many methods to update the data but it always says 200 OK in postman but not update the Mysql table.Here is my code

```
$data = $request->validate([
      'dob' => 'required',
      'gender'=>'required|in:male,female',
      'image'=>'required|mimes:jpg,png,jped|max:5048'
  ]);
  $newImage = time().'-'.$request->name.'.'.$request->image->extension();
  $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $newImage);

  $user = User::find($id);
  $user->update($request->all());
return response($user);
```

And this my output the name id and email field were added on the time of registeration what i am trying to add is 'dob','gender' and ''profile picture

[image]

After trying the method provided i got this
[image]

Comment: Why the SQL Server 2008 tag?

Comment: It's because of this: `if($user->update($request->all())){
 }`
It doesn't make any sense to put that condition inside the if statement . Just create a route for updating and make $user->update($request->all());

Comment: I tried this statement as well but it did not saved the data

Comment: @HassanAli Can you update the code with what you've tried ?

Comment: @workservice changed the code once again and output is still same. You can see code snipet.

Comment: please share your user model (User.php) - did you add the dob, gender and image to the fillable fields?

Comment: can you try to dd($request->all()); Also make sure you got the fields on protected $fillable

Comment: @Frnak yes i have added

Comment: well then add your model to the question here - also you should add your full implementation. I don't see where $id is coming from for example (maybe you just update the wrong user? also you don't make use of $newImage in the update - I guess you only want to store the link to the image, not the image itself directly on the user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user ->dob = $request->dob;
$user ->gender = $request->gender;
$user ->image= $newImage;
$user ->save();
```

try this will 100% update your users details .

I hope you got your solution .

Comment: now it says dob is required but i am passing the data through postman

Comment: check your dd out put    dd($request->all());

Comment: at best this is a mitigation of the problem, not a solution. It should be clarified why the update is not working instead of setting every field individually and calling save.

Comment: in data base make this colom  dob by default null

Comment: you are inserting date invalid format   can you tell me type dob colom

Comment: 2020-06-30   you have add dob like this

Comment: type of dob column is date. I have tried this before but it was still not helpful.

Comment: update type into timestamp  and also by default null

Comment: @Frnak i have provide only solution if you have any problem with solution then tell me

Comment: @RakeshkumarOad did the same but still same output

Comment: @Frnak which solution

Comment: you have to dd and get your dob value in controller

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was don't use 'PUT' request to update the data. Some times it works well and some times it will not work. Just use post method just like to create data. It solved my problem.